# How to get the feature name in Cucumber hooks.rb

Tags: ruby, cucumber, hook, scenarios

I need a variable that contains the name of the feature: since it's a feature, do it; since it is another, do that.

I tried these ways, but no success:

Examples:

**1)**

```
After do |scenario|
    puts scenario.feature.name
end
```

**2)**

```
After do |scenario|
    puts scenario.scenario_outline.feature.name
end
```

p.s.: Translated by Google

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found it!

```
Before do |s|
  feature(s.location) # => #<struct Cucumber::Core::Test::Location::Precise
end

def feature(location)
        string = File.read(location.file)
        document = ::Gherkin::Parser.new.parse(string)
        document[:feature]
end
```

The solution is in the clink below:

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-ruby/issues/1432

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would just be

```
After do |scenario|
  puts scenario.name
end
```

Comment: I already tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: @Johw I don't know what to tell you, that's how you access the scenario name in Cucumber - You're going to have to add a lot more details for anyone to figure out why that isn't working for you.

Comment: This works for the scenario, but my question is regarding feature.